# Trouble working with Square Connect ChargeResponse object

Tags: php, square-connect, square

I'm able to successfully charge using the transaction API following the example on github. Executing the charge looks like this:

```
$result = $transaction_api->charge($access_token, $location_id, $request_body);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Here's the output:

```
SquareConnect\Model\ChargeResponse Object
(
    [errors:protected] => 
    [transaction:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Transaction Object
        (
            [id:protected] => REMOVED FROM POST
            [location_id:protected] => REMOVED FROM POST
            [created_at:protected] => 2016-04-30T23:42:33Z
            [tenders:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SquareConnect\Model\Tender Object
                        (
                            [id:protected] => REMOVED FROM POST
                            [location_id:protected] => REMOVED FROM POST
                            [transaction_id:protected] => 02d1d965-51fd-5023-68f5-0fcd148a263b
                            [created_at:protected] => 2016-04-30T23:42:33Z
                            [note:protected] => Online Transaction
                            [amount_money:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Money Object
                                (
                                    [amount:protected] => 6000
                                    [currency:protected] => USD
                                )

                            [processing_fee_money:protected] => 
                            [customer_id:protected] => 
                            [type:protected] => CARD
                            [card_details:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\TenderCardDetails Object
                                (
                                    [status:protected] => CAPTURED
                                    [card:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Card Object
                                        (
                                            [id:protected] => 
                                            [card_brand:protected] => VISA
                                            [last_4:protected] => 5858
                                            [exp_month:protected] => 
                                            [exp_year:protected] => 
                                            [cardholder_name:protected] => 
                                            [billing_address:protected] => 
                                        )

                                    [entry_method:protected] => KEYED
                                )

                            [cash_details:protected] => 
                        )

                )

            [refunds:protected] => 
            [reference_id:protected] => 
            [product:protected] => EXTERNAL_API
        )

)
```

My problem is that, while some places (such as [here](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/processing-payment-php/)) indicate that I'm supposed to get an array back from the charge method, I instead get a ChargeResponse object.

Within this object is a transaction object that contains all of the relevant information that I want to display to the customer once the transaction is complete, but it's protected, so trying to echo a transaction id, created_at time, or amount from this returned object fails.

I'm certain I'm doing something wrong, but I'm lost as to how to capture properties from the ChargeResponse object so that I can do useful things with it.

For instance, I've tried

```
echo($result->transaction['id']);
```

but all I get is:

Fatal error: Cannot access protected property

This may not even be the right way to attempt something like this, so I'm completely open to suggestions.

Comment: Edited the question to include the output.

Comment: The first suggestion gives the same error about not being able to access the protected property and the second and third suggestions do not parse as valid php.

Answer (score 9):

I managed to figure out that one must use the getTransaction method that's included in the object to get a usable form of the properties.

```
$transaction = $result->getTransaction();
```

Then you can just get properties out that you want:

```
$transactionID = $transaction["tenders"][0]["transaction_id"];
```

I'm rather annoyed that I didn't come across this anywhere in the documentation (in fact a google search of the entire docs.connect.squareup.com doesn't turn up a single reference to getTransaction). I had to stumble upon it when I was trying to reparse the original ChargeResponse object into an array using some other hack job.

Anyway, glad this is resolved. Wanted to leave this here for others.

Comment: This getTransaction function is documented in the Square Connect SDK at https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/lib/Model/ChargeResponse.php#L136

You are right though that there are not many examples yet for actually using their SDK.

Comment: this will do the same: $result['transaction']->getId();

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
$transaction_id = $result->getTransaction()->getId();
```

Comment: Can you please format your code, and elaborate in more detail why you believe that this answers the question?

Answer (score 2):

I came here with the same problem and then I had an aha moment.

Rather than point out a few of the function calls, here's how to find them all.

Simply look into the square library files that you have implemented in your solution.
In this case "Transaction.php" found in the "model" folder.

Rinse and repeat for all the other objects (IE: Tenders.php).

I hope this saves time for some people because I wasted far too much before figuring it out.

## Verbatim from Transaction.php

```
'id' => 'getId',
'location_id' => 'getLocationId',
'created_at' => 'getCreatedAt',
'tenders' => 'getTenders',
'refunds' => 'getRefunds',
'reference_id' => 'getReferenceId',
'product' => 'getProduct',
'client_id' => 'getClientId',
'shipping_address' => 'getShippingAddress',
'order_id' => 'getOrderId'
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone looking for code with square connects v2 API than using this:

```
$payments_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\PaymentsApi($api_client);
$result = $payments_api->createPayment($request_body);
echo '<br/>';

// to get ID.
print_r( $result->getPayment()->getId() );
echo '<br/>';

// to get Reference ID.
print_r( $result->getPayment()->getReferenceId() );
echo '<br/>';

// to get Amount.
print_r( $result->getPayment()->getAmountMoney()->getAmount() );
echo '<br/>';

// to get Currency.
print_r( $result->getPayment()->getAmountMoney()->getCurrency() );
echo '<br/>';

// to get CreatedAt datetime.
print_r( $result->getPayment()->getCreatedAt() );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install square connect through composer then you can use its pre-defined functions.
$data holds the request for transaction

```
$body = new \SquareConnect\Model\ChargeRequest($data);
$transaction = $transactions_api->charge($location_id, $body);
$transactionId = $transaction->getTransaction()->getId();
```

Now you will be having transaction id in $transactionId variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $payments_api->createPayment($request_body);

print_r($result->getPayment()->getStatus());

print_r( $result->getPayment()->getId() );

print_r( $result->getPayment()->getReferenceId() );

print_r( $result->getPayment()->getAmountMoney()->getAmount() );

print_r( $result->getPayment()->getAmountMoney()->getCurrency() );

print_r( $result->getPayment()->getCreatedAt() );
```

Comment: You should add some explanation. What's going on and how does this answer the question?